# How to draw a fish using Tkinter-canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to draw a fish in a bowl using the defined Canvas class using tkinter. I drew a cube, and work completed 50%, but I need help in drawing the fish in a bowl. How can I draw a fish using Tkinter Canvas? Help me, please!

This is what I want to achieve

[image: Link]

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('graphics')

canv = Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 800, bg = "white", cursor = "pencil")

canv.create_line(150, 250, 450, 250, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(150, 550, 450, 550, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(150, 250, 150, 550, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(450, 250, 450, 550, width = 2, fill = "black")

canv.create_line(300, 150, 600, 150, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(300, 450, 600, 450, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(300, 150, 300, 450, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(600, 150, 600, 450, width = 2, fill = "black")

canv.create_line(150, 250, 300, 150, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(450, 250, 600, 150, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(150, 550, 300, 450, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(450, 550, 600, 450, width = 2, fill = "black")

canv.create_line(150, 300, 300, 200, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(450, 300, 600, 200, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(150, 300, 450, 300, width = 2, fill = "black")
canv.create_line(300, 200, 600, 200, width = 2, fill = "black")

canv.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We can't do your code for you, but try using commands like ```canv.create_arc``` and ```canv.create_oval```.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply!